# Finding percentage using mongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I have a collection of 2 documents. Each document has bank[ ] array which has objects in it.

There are 3 banks : ABC, PQR, XYZ.

For document 1

`banks[{name:"PQR", pdf:true, amt: 500}, {name:"ABC", amt:300}]`

For document 2

`banks[{name:"XYZ", pdf:true, amt:450}, {name:"PQR", amt:200}, {name:"ABC",pdf:true, amt:600}]`

I am trying to find percentage for each bank that has pdf value true in it.

Consider bank ABC

Total occurances: 2

Occurances with "pdf:true" key: 1

Percentage: 50

I want result something like this

`{name:"ABC", percentage: 50}`

Similarly I want to find for remaining banks.
How can I do it with aggregation. Please help
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I started with [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) to flatten the `banks` array
- And then used [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) for parallel grouping.

  Created two groups:

  - `pdfTrue` which has the count of documents with `pdf=true` for each bank name.
  - `total` which has the total count of documents per bank name.
- And then found the percentage after concatenating both `pdfTrue` and `total` arrays and grouping based on bank name.

You can achieve your use case using the following method:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$banks"
  },
  {
    "$facet": {
      "pdfTrue": [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$banks.name",
            count: {
              $sum: {
                $cond: [
                  {
                    $eq: [
                      "$banks.pdf",
                      true
                    ]
                  },
                  1,
                  0
                ]
              }
            },
            
          }
        }
      ],
      "total": [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$banks.name",
            count: {
              "$sum": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            total: "$count"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      concat: {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$total",
          "$pdfTrue"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$concat"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$concat._id",
      values: {
        $mergeObjects: {
          count: "$concat.count",
          total: "$concat.total",
          
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "_id": 0,
      "name": "$_id",
      "percentage": {
        $multiply: [
          {
            $divide: [
              "$values.count",
              "$values.total"
            ]
          },
          100
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See the output here: [MongoDB Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/B8CRZ8j3gyk)

Comment: @RohanDevasthale I have grouped based on ```banks.name```  in ```total``` sub pipeline stage. So in the above query, for ABC it is giving 2 as count (see ```total``` field in ```total``` array). You can verify it here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/wjVvZ1I6js9

Comment: Thank you. I had one more question, How can I get 0 as count if "pdf:true" condition does not match. Lets say I have fourth bank named JKL. Its count for "pdf:true" is zero. How can I get that count as well?

Comment: To get count 0, use $cond along with $sum in the group stage. Eg: https://mongoplayground.net/p/bU0ZcoBylHB Full output can be found here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/B8CRZ8j3gyk I'm also updating the answer to handle this condition